# Element UI Table column adjust to content

Tags: element-ui

How do I have a column that will adjust to the width of his contents?
So if the content is wider, the column will adjust to that size, without breaking words.

Answer (score 0):

That will do the trick. Let me know if it works.

```
<el-table-column
  prop="XXXXXXX"
  sortable="custom"
  label="XXXXXXX"
  max-width: max-content
>
```